# Bitbucket - view repos shared with me

Tags: bitbucket

In bitbucket, I'm getting people to share private repos with me. When they share a repo, I don't ever get an email saying they shared it, there's apparently no automatic email saying 'So-and-so shared this repo with you, click this link to view', and I can't find any place on Bitbucket to click a link to see a list of repos shared with me.

Is there any way to view repos shared with me? Or any setting that I can click to send me an email when someone shares with me?

[edit] -- In settings > notifications, there's a setting called **Email me about: My access to a repository or a team changing.** I have this setting already ticked though, so... that can't be it.

Comment: Do you not see all your repositories after simply clicking on the bitbucket symbol at the top left?

Comment: I see all of my own respositories and anything I've contributed to, but not any repositories that are external to my business, that have been shared with me by a random third party

Comment: Same here, a year later after this question was posted. Client just told me they shared repo with me, sent me screenshot to prove it. I still don't see it anywhere in my account.